# Very light jQuery edit-in-place solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, edit-in-place

Are you guys aware of a edit-in-place type of plugin that's very simple and small?

What I need is just to replace a text I click with a editable input, which gets submitted with ajax on blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable): Edit In Place Plugin For jQuery

Comment: That plugin appears to be written for a **very** outdated version of jQuery. There is no guarantee it'll "just work" with newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this plugin [inedit](http://webolitic.com/inedit) it is very light